# ARCore Cloud Anchor Device Compatibility

Tags: android, augmented-reality, arcore, android-augmented-reality

I want to try out the ARCore Cloud Anchors across multiple devices. So far I have a Huawei P30 Pro and a Sony Xperia XZ2 (all up-to-date) and I build the ARCore Example for Cloud Anchors with Unity.

According to the ARCore Documentation, both devices are supported:
[AR Core Supported Devices](https://developers.google.com/ar/discover/supported-devices)

While the P30 Pro works fine, the XZ2 wants to install the [Google Play Services for AR](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.ar.core), but according to the PlayStore the phone is not supported. So I copied the APK to to the XZ2 and installed it, but the example app just won't work. (After entering/hosting a room the App crashes.)

Is there a way, to tell which devices are supported for ARCore Cloud Anchors / Google PlayServices for AR?